# XML3D API methods and scene hierarchy

Tags: javascript, xml, xml3d

I'm using [XML3D library](http://xml3d.org/) to make a simple 3D editor.
I wonder if the users of this library are supposed to use its API too or just treat this lib as a tool that renders scene from XML scene definition.

First thing i need would be to create some *js* scene representation.
There is a plenty of tool for *XML*->*JSON* conversion but maybe accessing the *XML3D* internal scene representation would be the better way to handle scene modification.

Could you please give me any advices on scene manipulation with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of XML3D is to use the [DOM API](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) to modify the 3D scene representation. Thus, manipulating the scene is as simple as modifying a web page. For instance, if you have a mesh:

```
<mesh id="teapot" src="teapot.json"></mesh>
```

you can add an event listener like this:

```
document.querySelector("#teapot").addEventListener("click", function() {
   alert("Hallo");
});
```

or with jQuery, removing the mesh from the scene:

```
$("#teapot").remove();
```

Some more examples can also be found in the [xml3d.js wiki](https://github.com/xml3d/xml3d.js/wiki/Adding-Interactivity-With-Event-Listeners).